# Redhat 7.5 unable to install pyarrow

Tags: rhel

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
When executing the below command: ( I get the following error)
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install pyarrow

  cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3.8  -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /tmp/pip-install-egbiwnvg/pyarrow
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
  -- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Compiler command: env LANG=C /bin/c++ -v
  -- Compiler version: Using built-in specs.
  COLLECT_GCC=/bin/c++
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
  Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
  Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
  Thread model: posix
  gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)

  -- Compiler id: GNU
  Selected compiler gcc 4.8.5
  -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_SSE4_2
  -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_SSE4_2 - Success
  -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_ALTIVEC
  -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_ALTIVEC - Failed
  -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_ARMCRC
  -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_ARMCRC - Failed
  -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_ARMV8_CRC_CRYPTO
  -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_ARMV8_CRC_CRYPTO - Failed
  -- Arrow build warning level: PRODUCTION
  Using ld linker
  Configured for RELEASE build (set with cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE={release,debug,...})
  -- Build Type: RELEASE
  -- Build output directory: /tmp/pip-install-egbiwnvg/pyarrow/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/release
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 (found version "3.8")
  -- Searching for Python libs in /usr/local/lib64;/usr/local/lib;/usr/local/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu
  -- Looking for python3.8
  -- Found Python lib /usr/local/lib/libpython3.8.a
  -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.8.a
  CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindNumPy.cmake:62 (message):
    NumPy import failure:

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:189 (find_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/tmp/pip-install-egbiwnvg/pyarrow/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/tmp/pip-install-egbiwnvg/pyarrow/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
  Running setup.py clean for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` - so try installing numpy first ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `numpy` is missing. Try with `python -m pip install --upgrade numpy pip`. If this not solve the problem, you need to install `numpy` from `yum`